# Dynamically change input names when appending to an existing div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form in which I need to add new inputs based on user interaction. When the page loads, the form looks like this:

```
<li class="basic">
    <h4 class="secondary-title" style="margin-top: 0px;">Specifications</h4>
    <span style="float: right; margin-top: -40px;"><a href="#" class="add_specification_group"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add group</a></span>
</li>
<li id="specifications">
    <div class="specification_group" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="label">
            Specification group     
        </div>
        <input name="specification_group_title1[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Group title" value="">
        <a href="#" class="add_specification_group_field"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add field</a><br />             
        <input name="specification_name1[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Name"> 
        <input name="specification_value1[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Value"> 
    </div>
</li>
```

I user can either click on the "Add group" link in order to add a new group, or on the "Add field" link to add fields to one of the existing groups.

The HTML for the group or fields is taken from a template.

```
<script type="text/template" id="specification_group_template">
    <div class="specification_group" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <div class="label">
            Specification group     
        </div>
        <input name="specification_group_title[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Group title" value=""> 
        <a href="#" class="add_specification_group_field"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add field</a><br />             
        <input name="specification_name[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Name"> 
        <input name="specification_value[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Value">                             
    </div>                        
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="specification_group_field_template">
    <div class="specification_group">                                        
        <input name="specification_name[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Name"> 
        <input name="specification_value[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Value">                             
    </div>                        
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(function() {                                                                
            var groupCount = 1;

            $('.add_specification_group').on('click', function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#specifications').append($('#specification_group_template').html());
                groupCount++;
            });

            $('#specifications').on('click', '.add_specification_group_field', function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parents('div.specification_group').append($('#specification_group_field_template').html()).find('input:last');
            });                             
        });
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

Everything is fine right now, but I would like to modify this code so whenever I add a new group, the input names should be modified based on the `groupCount` variable value.

So if the user clicks "Add group", the appended HTML should be:

```
<div class="specification_group" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="label">
        Specification group     
    </div>
    <input name="specification_group_title2[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Group title" value="">
    <a href="#" class="add_specification_group_field"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add field</a><br />             
    <input name="specification_name2[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Name"> 
    <input name="specification_value2[]" type="text" class="short" placeholder="Value"> 
</div>
```

Also, when a user decides to add new fields to an existing group, the inputs should be renamed and the group index value should be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the values before adding the html:

```
$('.add_specification_group').on('click', function(e) { 
                        e.preventDefault();
                       var html = $('#specification_group_template').html();
                       html = html.replace('specification_name[]', 'specification_name' + groupCount + '[]');
                       html = html.replace('specification_value[]', 'specification_value' + groupCount + '[]');
                       $('#specifications').append(html);
                        groupCount++;
                    });
```

You can save the group number in a data attribute on the group main div, just add it to the replace:

```
$('.add_specification_group').on('click', function(e) { 
                            e.preventDefault();
                           var html = $('#specification_group_template').html();
                           html = html.replace('specification_name[]', 'specification_name' + groupCount + '[]');
                           html = html.replace('specification_value[]', 'specification_value' + groupCount + '[]');
                           html = html.replace('div class="specification_group"', 'div data-group-no="' + groupCount + '" class="specification_group"');
                           $('#specifications').append(html);
                            groupCount++;
                        });
```

Then retrieve it and replace when adding new fields:

```
$('#specifications').on('click', '.add_specification_group_field', function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
  var parent = $(this).parents('div.specification_group');
  var groupNo = parent.attr('data-group-no');
  var html = $('#specification_group_field_template').html();
  html = html.replace('specification_name[]', 'specification_name' + groupNo + '[]');
                           html = html.replace('specification_value[]', 'specification_value' + groupNo + '[]');

parent.append(html).find('input:last');
            });
```

Comment: Great! So simple!

Comment: There is one problem though. When the user adds new fields in an existing group, the inputs need to be renamed based on the number of that group.

Comment: I added some ideas on how to check an existing group number, see if that helps.